# I literally cannot use .getDisplayValue() with parseInt()

Tags: google-apps-script

```
console.log(parseInt('-3')) //returns "Information -3"
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
console.log(typeof(ss.getRange('G4').getDisplayValue())) //returns "Information String"
var result = parseInt(ss.getRange('G4').getDisplayValue());
console.log(result) //returns "Information NaN"
```

The Original Cell is "=IF(E4;((B4-10)/2)+B3;((B4-10)/2))" (E4 being a toggle, B3 being (2+1/4 with decimals removed), B4 being 4.)
Even though both are negative three as a string they return different things and therefore i basically cant use negative numbers in my project...

[proving that 'G4' is -3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bECUy.png)

Comment: For example, in your situation, when `console.log(ss.getRange('G4').getDisplayValue())` is run, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike NaN still

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `@Tanaike NaN still`, I cannot understand the answer to my question of `For example, in your situation, when console.log(ss.getRange('G4').getDisplayValue()) is run, what result will you obtain?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your reply?

Comment: @Tanaike Instead of getting an Integer like I am looking for to display in a cell, I get an "NaN" which is not an integer nor a string so I cannot use it

Comment: console.log is just a debugging tool in this scenario

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, `console.log(ss.getRange('G4').getDisplayValue())` returns `NaN`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike yes it is, also editted the originial question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `yes it is`, I understood that `console.log(ss.getRange('G4').getDisplayValue())` returns `NaN`. In this case, it is considered that the showing cell value is `NaN`. When the cell value is `NaN`, `var result = parseInt(ss.getRange('G4').getDisplayValue());` returns `NaN`. If the cell value is `-3`, `console.log(ss.getRange('G4').getDisplayValue())` returns `-3`. By this, `var result = parseInt(ss.getRange('G4').getDisplayValue());` returns `-3`. I'm worried that this is the reason of your issue. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your time, found out the problem however :)

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem, if you exchange `getDisplayValue()` to `getValue()` it simply works...